# Can recv return EHOSTUNREACH?

Tags: sockets, unix, recv

According Unix Network Programming by Stevens, EHOSTUNREACH can be returned when readline\recv is used.
However, in linux man pages, EHOSTUNREACH  cannot be received by recv.

Who is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an error occurs in the communication the error will be set on the socket and delivered with the next syscall related to the socket. The EHOSTUNREACH error can be (among other things) triggered by sending a UDP packet to a target and getting an ICMP unreachable back. Since this ICMP message comes back only after the `send` call was done it will not returned for the `send` but only on the next syscall on the socket which might also be a `recv`.

Thus I would suggest that this error can be returned in Linux too but I might be wrong. In generally Linux is not UNIX, systems evolve and documentation is often flawed. If you look at the documentation for recv on various platforms you will see that [OpenBSD documents EHOSTUNREACHABLE](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=recv&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+5.7&arch=default&format=html) as possible error while FreeBSD, NetBSD, Linux... do not. I would suggest you better expect the unexpected :)